# How can i display react-native's tabbar at the top of the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabs, position

TabBarposition='top' makes application collapse due to react-native-router-flux ( or navigation ) update. It used to work , but now i get this error:[image]

My code :[image]

Answer (score 1):

since react-native 0.61.2 the Viewpagerandroid has removed form react-native, but the tab library you use it has not update to adapt it.
   Firstly, you find the library file which used Viewpagerandroid, then import it
from react-native-viewpager.

For example, I use react-native-scrollable-view, the ScrollableTabView use it.
I delete the import in the react-native, and import it from @react-native-community/viewpager

```
const {
     Dimensions,
     View,
     Animated,
     ScrollView,
     Platform,
     StyleSheet,
     //ViewPagerAndroid //**delete it**
     InteractionManager,
   } = ReactNative;
   const ViewPagerAndroid = require("@react-native-community/viewpager")
```

the other way is to check whether the library's new version adapts it.

Comment: ok i get your point.But still how is it possible, when i remove the property tabBarPosition, everything works just fine?

Comment: @Vagtse I find the source code, only in the old react-native-tab-view  I find TabViewPagerAndroid, it used in TabViewAnimated, but it did not relate with the position. So I do not know why happen

Answer (score 0):

You are using older method of ViewPagerAndroid. Old one is deprecated with new one with react-native-community. You can see the channel log [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecated). 
That means if you are using ViewPagerAndroid now you can use new one instead of old one.
You can view the new ViewPager repo [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager/blob/master/README.md)

Install the new library first

```
yarn add @react-native-community/viewpager
```

or

```
npm install @react-native-community/viewpager --save
```

If you are using RN >= 0.60 then no need to link, autolink will do that 
If you are using RN < 0.60 run `react-native link @react-native-community/viewpager`

Or manual linking read the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager/blob/master/README.md#manual-linking)

Then remove old ViewPagerAndroid imports

```
import { ViewPagerAndroid } from 'react-native'; //Remove this import
```

Import ViewPager separate like this

```
import ViewPager from '@react-native-community/viewpager'; //New way of importing
```

If you still getting the error please try to remove the app and re-install it.

Comment: i do not use the Viewpager at all and also removed and re-installed the app already.The problem appears only with the tabBarPosition property only.If i remove it , everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `npm install` this happen. if you use tab in your screen do this steps:

1: delete node modules
2: comment your tab code
3: yarn add ...(every package in your package.json)